# Best practice ASP.NET Controller for Common Actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a quick question,

In so many examples I saw controller Actions which does not return any View or Partialview are also added in the same controller - Now in my situation i have multiple controllers which i need to run same ACTIONS such as

- Controller A will Run Action A
- Controller B will run Action A

Adding Action A in both Controller A and B does not look right.

As I am making `[HttpPost]` calls for Action A using AJAX, therefore, i want this to be in a Controller for easy POST access, although I don't want to add the same Action in both Controllers

I can add action A in Controller A and let Controller B access the same action requesting from Controller A instead but what I was thinking

**How about if I create a new Controller called

> commonActionContoller

and put "ACTION A" in it and let everything use commonActionContoller when Action A is required?**

Cheers

**EDIT: Example added as following**

An example application which has Person and Countries, So Person model is the same for all Countries but we have different Controller for each country so If an Admin wants to update Person's model with field IsEmpoyed from true to false then they go to for example {USA}/Index controller and switch true to false. Now, this is same for {AUS}/Index and {China}/Index so Action which changes IsEmpyed to true/false is the same across all controllers. To make this work i don't want to add Action IsEmplyed to all country controllers - (Couldn't think of a better example) –

Comment: what does `action a` actualy do?

Comment: The approach you specified sounds viable. A `CommonActionController` for having common actions to be called from several other controller-actions.

Comment: @deezg Gets data and Sets data if required and returns data if required

Comment: so, its actually not a controller action but some service. in that case, create separate service class and use dependency injection to put it in all controllers where you need it.

Comment: But the question still remains: If you call the `CommonAction` from `ControllerA` or from `ControllerB`, where would you return back? I mean how would you determine which action called upon this `CommonAction`?

Comment: @deezg this is the approach I currently have but it still doesn't resolve it, Basically, ACTION A is Calling a class/function and than on the bases of results ACTION A returns some data in Json `return Json(somedata, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: this smells to me as actually a REST API & routing design problem. you might provide a bit more infos about your routes and nature of your action you're talking about. / Which particular problem does extracting it to service not resolve?

Comment: @deezg i added an example in main post

Comment: well, the way i read that example is that you're replicating controllers for no reason. from info you provided i would just redesign routing. meaning, i would have a single controller with route `"{:country}/index"`, read `country` parameter from route and go from there. i don't see a need for controller per country in the first place. again, i am pretty sure you might want to rethink your rest api / routes design as first thing. not to mention that if something is the same for all 'controllers' (if they should be separate), then its a candidate for controller on its own.

Comment: first question to answer is: do i need separate controller per country and if so - why? what is the sole reason for that?

Comment: Each country has different PartialView as the display layout is completely different (html) - Also some countries don't show certain data fields

Comment: well, shouldn't then you be switching/replicating views and not controllers?

Comment: @deezg You are right . Making me re-think the approach - What you are saying makes perfect sense, one thing though, don't you think it will make my Country Controller very large for example i will have to do this for each country and their PartialViews? `public ActionResult USA()
        {
           retune view();
        }public ActionResult _allPersonListData_USA)(List<Models.Person> Model)
        {
            return PartialView(Model);
        }`

Comment: well, there are several things to consider here. first of all, a thin controller is a nice thing to have. what that means is that can think about controller as a pure mapper to user actions which is actually just a mapper to url endpoints. that makes me think that you'll actually have a very small controller, just a few endpoints. then, based on `country` parameter and potential differences in logic you want to perform per country, you would have service layer doing that. at the end, based on service layer result, controller would switch view. that would produce smallest codebase.

Comment: ah i see, So determine the Country Parameter on the-the-fly and render a view on that bases. One more thing though, don't you think it will make the application do more processing? As it is determining the country first and then rendering/returning the view on that bases so basically i will have `CASE` statement like process

Comment: you can forget about processing problem, there is no one.

Comment: WOW thank you so much. I think I can tackle this now, Instead of having so many controllers I can just return different views/PartialViews from the same controller :) Now I feel silly with my initial approach (although I had about 8 controllers in my app still, the approach was pretty silly) - I think I took an incorrect approach at the start of this application (new to MVC) and wanted to have "MORE" organised solution but I forgot that making a solution more structural or organise doesn't mean creating unnecessary objects to overload your application - How can I mark you answer as "Answered?"

Comment: im commenting for later reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guiding principle here should be Separation Of Concerns.

If ControllerA and ControllerB have specific business logic, and adding a CommonActions controller give shared data a good isolated home this is a good practice.

Without a better illustration of your needs though it's difficult to answer.

A slightly better example might be the order application:

InventoryController
EmployeeController

You probably don't want a CommomController with methods like:

```
GetStoreClosingHours(int storeNumber);
GetTotalSales(int employeeId);
GetEmployeeComps(int employeeId);
```

IoC and dependency injection might pay off as well depending on the actions. Where any controller could call methods like:

```
GetLastLogonTime(thisEmployee);
```

It's really a set of principles designing your application after all, and best practices aren't always super neatly packaged. I'd say most importantly choose something flexible, scalable and then stick with it.

Comment: That makes sense, an example application which has Person and Countries, So Person model is the same for all Countries but we have different Controller for each country so If an Admin wants to update Person's model with field `IsEmpoyed` from `true` to `false` then they go to for example {USA}/Index controller and switch true to false. Now, this is same for {AUS}/Index and {China}/Index so Action which changes IsEmpyed to true/false is the same across all controllers. To make this work i don't want to add Action IsEmplyed to all country controllers - (Couldn't think of a better example)

Comment: In that case... IoC or inheritance might be a great middle ground.... Although do nation's really have anything to do with employment? An HrController might be good.

Answer (score 1):

You should write Action `A` in both Controller. Otherwise it will violate [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Best practice is to move the implementation codes from Controller to a Service layer. For example, if you want to load Product Category for Products and Sub-Categories, then code will be like this:

```
public interface ICategoryService
{
    List<Category> LoadCategory();
}

public class CategoryService : ICategoryService
{
    public List<Category> LoadCategory()
    {
        //code here
    }
}

public class ProductController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICategoryService _categoryService;
    public ProductController()
    {
        _categoryService = <inject dependency here>;
    }

    public ActionResult GetCategory()
    {
        var category = _categoryService.LoadCategory();
    }
}

public class SubCategoryController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICategoryService _categoryService;
    public SubCategoryController()
    {
        _categoryService = <inject dependency here>;
    }

    public ActionResult GetCategory()
    {
        var category = _categoryService.LoadCategory();
    }
}
```

Comment: I will have to repeat my 3 ACTIONS into 8 different CONTROLLERS  - Isn't that just extra line of codes - there might be a better way to deal with this? It just doesn't sound right to repeat same ACTIONS over 8 different Controllers. What are your thoughts

Comment: Create an extra service layer.

Comment: I think i am not explaining it well - Sorry, i do have a service Layer but the issue is i still have to call that Service Layer from my ACTION for example in the following code `[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetAccess(string accessCode)
{
    var userToken = User.Identity.GetUserToken();
    string errorMessage;
 
    if (!_userService.ClaimAccessCode(accessCode, userToken, 
                                      out errorMessage))
    Do something
}` So i still WILL have to add ACTION A on each controller to access the Service Layer

Comment: Code optimization is not always good. After optimizing, you may understand your code. But other have to face difficulty to understand your code.

Comment: Ok thank you, and yes all my code is outside the controller, I am just calling it from Controller Actions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156618/discussion-between-jaber-and-aliusman).